Dynamic Background Generation for a ZPL String (Black Background And Inverted Text)
I'm trying to generate a text with black background and white font text in ZPL through code.
I have come up with a way of calculating the text width according to the characters. (not the most efficient way)
With the calculated text width I generate the background with a padding of 30 (don't know the UOM) and then moving the text X position +15 to the right.
It seems to be working. But I would like to have a more accurate error correction calculation and generate the text right within the box.
And bonus if there is a dynamic way to adjust with the font width (using 60 here) that would help a lot.
I'm putting up the code snippet here.
public static void Main()
{
    var characterWidths = new Dictionary<char, int>
    {
        {'1', 24},
        {'I', 13},
        {'M', 45},
        {'W', 50},
        {'-', 53},
        {'J', 25}
    };
    int textWidth = 0;

    string text = "LAX-FJ-LV-01";

    textWidth = text.Sum(c => char.IsDigit(c) && c != '1' ? 29 : characterWidths.GetValueOrDefault(c, 34));

    int boxWidth = textWidth + 30;
    int fixedXPosition = 750;
    int backgroundXPosition = fixedXPosition - textWidth;

    backgroundXPosition = backgroundXPosition < 0 ? 0 : backgroundXPosition;

    int textXPosition = backgroundXPosition == 0 ? 0 : backgroundXPosition + 15;

    string zplCode = $@"^XA
^FO{backgroundXPosition},480^GB{boxWidth},90,85^FS
^FO{textXPosition},500^A0N,60,60^FR^FD{text}^FS
^XZ";

    Console.WriteLine(zplCode);
}

This is my first time working with ZPL and I know very basic commands and would like to keep it as less complicated as possible (with the ZPL and not the code). I have tried few ways but no good.

Use the fact that ^FT can carry on from the point where the previous ^FT ended.
Draw the black background to the end of the label, print the text, erase the unwanted background using the ^FT's implicit last coordinates:
^XA

^MUm
^FT10,10^GB100,5,5^FS
^FT10,9.5^A0,5^FR^FD SomeText ^FS
^FT,10^GB100,5,5,W^FS
^MUd

^XZ

View the result here.

Wow! Thank you.... You are a god send!

Is there a possibility that this could generate the text from right to left with a fixed right position?

Do you mean right aligned or right-to-left reversed?

The text generation from right to left.

To have txeTemoS on the label? I don't know; you can have the text with ^FPR, but it's not clear where the ^FT's implicit coordinates will be after that. The emulator puts them as if SomeText was written left to right, and I don't know if that's what the printer does too, or it's a quirk of the emulator. In any case you cannot use the implicit ^FT coordinates as the ending point of a ^GB, only as a starting point, and ^GB is drawn from left to right.
